# Модуль использует другие модули - как принято оформлять

Tags: node.js, npm, модули

Делаю модуль, который использует в работе другие модули, часть из которых надо импортировать из npm (node js).

Хочется узнать у опытных разработчиков, как принято делать, чтобы сразу привыкать к определенной схеме работы.

1. Включать все эти модули в готовую сборку сразу (удобно устанавливать - кинул папку и всё, но получается большой вес).
2. Можно просто указать в package.json моего модуля необходимый перечень. В этом случае перед использованием придется отдельно запускать npm i из директории модуля, ведь корневое приложение не будет изучать все вложенные модули (если я верно понимаю).
3. Либо в описании к модулю указать, что приложение его использующее должно содержать еще несколько модулей и их необходимо добавить в основное приложение, использующее мой модуль.

Часто вижу, что применяется вариант 3, но сам на практике убеждаюсь, что это бывает неудобно, так как используемые модули могут измениться, исчезнуть и т.д.

Comment: 2.  npm автоматически установит рекурсивные зависимости.

Comment: Как я понимаю, это в случае когда мой модуль сам будет лежать в npm? При локальной работе npm закачивает только то что в package.json приложения, тот что в модуле он не использует - только вручную. Возможно причина в том, что свой модуль я кладу в отдельную папку, а не в node_modules

Comment: И зачем вы кладёте его в отдельную папку? Ну и вообще, есть куча гайдов как правильно разрабатывать пакеты под ноду

Comment: Клал в отдельную, чтобы не путать свое с общественным. Спасибо, разобрался. В node_modules npm всё видит, главное не забывать прописать этот модуль в package.json, чтоб при установке не удалился.